Simulating in Pyomo DAE with user-defined input signals
I am using Pyomo DAE to simulate a system of ODEs of a chemical process with exogeneous inputs. How can I design a random input signal to perturb my system?
My current input design is a step change at time t = 2 from a value of F2 = 2 kg/min to 3 kg/min. The code that works for me is as follows:
def _step(m, i):
    if i < 2:
        return m.F2[i] == 2
    else:
        return m.F2[i] == 3

model.stepConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.t, rule=_step)

However, if I want to design a piecewise series of steps for F2, I wish to avoid making a lot of if-elif statements. What I tried is the following, but it doesn't work. How should this constraint be modified?
def _step(m, i):
    F2data = np.array([2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3])
    i_data = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
    return m.F2[i] == F2data[np.argwhere(i>=i_data)[-1]]

model.stepConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.t, rule=_step)

